# Ruby: POST data to a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails app I want to be able to post some information to another website inside a method without visiting the website. I'm fairly new to the topic so act as if I’m 5 years old.

My idea so far:

```
def create_button
  button = {
    :name => 'test',
    :type => 'buy_now',
    :callback_url => 'http://www.example.com/my_custom_button_callback',
    :description => 'sample description',
    :include_email => true
  }
  "https://thesite.com/api/v1" + button.to_query
  # post logic here

end
```

Comment: I noticed you unmarked me as an answer. Did it not work?

Comment: yeah i got "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" I'm trying to figure it out now. When I do i'm going to mark you correct

Comment: check out my code https://gist.github.com/alaingoldman/8632322

Answer (score 1):

Ruby ships with the Net::HTTP library for making HTTP requests. There are a lot of gems that wrap HTTP as well, my favorite is [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). Look into those libraries, it is pretty straightforward how to make a POST request with them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lots of gems that do this for free but if you only want to use the standard library, try something like this:

```
require "net/http"
require 'net/https'
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://thesite.com/api/v1")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

# I'm unsure if symbols will work
button = {
  "name" => 'test',
  "type" => 'buy_now',
  "callback_url" => 'http://www.example.com/my_custom_button_callback',
  "description"  => 'sample description',
  "include_email" => true
}
req.set_form_data(button)
res = https.request(req)
```

Comment: Ok sweet, could you possibly point me to a tutorial so I can understand it. Thanks a bunch either way!

Comment: What part do you feel least comfortable with? I'm happy to explain it. I just read the documentation and googled "ruby net/http post request."

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to implement it now. I'll definitely come back with questions if it doesn’t work lol. Give me a second.

Answer (score 1):

Try: [Net::HTTP](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP)

```
uri = URI.parse("https://thesite.com/api/v1")
button = {
 :name => 'test',
 :type => 'buy_now',
 :callback_url => 'http://www.example.com/my_custom_button_callback',
 :description => 'sample description',
 :include_email => true
}
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri,button)
res.code 
res.body  # response from api
```