# how to post to form from within an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link that goes to an action, so if someone clicks:

```
localhost/cart/checkout?pid=123
```

It goes to the CartController checkout action which then displays a form.

But in some circumstances (depending on when I load the Product with id 123) I may not need to display the form, I can just load the data and then post to the form's action.

How can I programatically post to where my form was going to post with data.

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  def checkout
    pid = params[:pid]
    product = Product.find(pid)
    if product....
       # no need to display view, just post to handleCheckout
    end
  end

  # checkout form posts to this action
  def handleCheckout
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not a ruby developer, so forgive if I am mistaken, but can't you just send the request something like this :  [Ruby: POST data to a url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20769173/3504007)  it looks like it uses `Net::HTTP` to directly post the raw data to the URL.  The second solution on the page appears to get the response back as `body` - both with no output to the page (only server to server calls)

Comment: Maybe you could take a look of [Resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). This should solve your problem.

Comment: @bananaappletw how does that solve it?

Comment: @Blankman
`GET /cart/:id => "show data"`

`GET /cart/new => "show form"`

`POST /cart => "create data"`

Comment: @bananaappletw I don't think you have understood the question sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done something like this before but I have some idea so please note that none of the is tested.

If your `handleCheckout` action is meant to be used as a `Get` request then you can redirect to this action with the params. like:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  def checkout
    pid = params[:pid]
    product = Product.find(pid)
    if product....
       redirect_to action: "handleCheckout", params: params
       # Not sure whether you will get it as 'params' or params[:params] in handleCheckout action
    end
  end

  # checkout form posts to this action
  def handleCheckout
  end
end
```

And if `handleCheckout` is meant to be used as `post` Then above method might not work since `redirect_to` will create a new `http Get` request to that action. so you may try something like this:

```
def checkout
    pid = params[:pid]
    product = Product.find(pid)
    if product....
       handleCheckout
       # params since is a global hash and above method has access to it
    end
end

# checkout form posts to this action
def handleCheckout
   # your other code
   redirect_to 'some_action' and return
   # in above line you have to return with a render or redirect
   # Otherwise it will render 'checkout' template with render and redirect or
   # it will throw double render error if you have a simple render or redirect without explicit return
end
```

As I mentioned, I have not tried any of above code. There might be errors. I hope it helps.